# Opening a terminal from within a python script + changing directory and executing commands?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, gnome-terminal

I've tried a variation of os.system and subprocess commands but I can't seem to figure this out. I am able to open a new terminal from a python script into a specific directory using the following:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/USERNAME/Documents/Scripts/"
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

I have a bash script which contains all my commands. Is there a way I can automatically execute it in the newly opened terminal?

**To recap, this is my goal:**

- Upon running script.py from one terminal, I would like it to open a second terminal at a specific directory.
- Execute a command in the new directory.
- Execute a second command in the same directory.
- Leave the terminal open indefinitely (make it stay open)

If anyone can point me in the right direction I can try to implement this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have this piece of code to read output of terminal:

```py
def verbosecmd(command):
    with Popen(
        command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, close_fds=True
    ) as process:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):
            print(line.rstrip().decode("utf-8"))
```

If your script continues, it will not close the terminal as long as the command still executed.

Regarding your goal, have you consider using `&&`?

```py
command = ("cd /home/USERNAME/Documents/Scripts/"
           " && first command"
           " && second command"
          )  # NOTE: don't use comma between string and use space before `&&`
```